# Difference between render 'posts' and render posts (without quotes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionviewhelper

I was going through a video and where he was rendering something like below example:

```
<div>
 <%= render posts %> # no quotes to posts
</div>
```

Though he has even created a partial with `_posts.html.erb`, he is calling with quotes to posts.

Though he has mentioned something about it like it calls, active record model, then class and then something...i could not understand it properly. Can anyone explain clearly this with simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With quotes then you are explicitly rendering a partial of that name. Without quotes something quite interesting is happening. posts (without quotes) is a variable that will be an activemodel list of records.

Now what the call to render does is it will look at the type of each of the models and then find the correct partial for the model (which will be the name of the model camel_cased) and render each one in turn.

EDIT:

If you have a model called `Post` and you assign some of those records to a variable (he uses `posts` I assume but I'll use `foo` to disambiguate) like so:

```
foo = Post.all
```

then by calling `render foo` the render function will see that you have an activerecord collection of records, it will then check the model associated with these records (`Post` in our example) and will loop through all of them rendering them to a partial called `_post.html.erb` with a local variable for each record assigning the record to `post`.

```
<%= render foo %>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<% foo.each do |my_post| %>
  <%= render partial: "post", locals: {post: my_post} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if i mention render posts, it will search for model called posts ?

Comment: i almost got it, just want to make sure that my understanding is clear, `render post` will look for variable inside Post model and then executes the query associated with that variable.. and then that results are rendered through our posts partial ?

Comment: No, `render post` doesn't execute any query. that happens earlier when you assign something to the `posts` variable. The thing that you assign will be the result of a query (such as `Post.all` as in my example). Then calling render on this variable (which is posts in your example, foo in mine to stop you getting confused) the render function checks the model associated with these records (`Post` as we got it from `Post.all` and then looks for a partial called `_post.html.erb` and passes the record into a local variable in that partial and renders it.

Answer (score 4):

Render with quotes

```
<%=render 'post'%>
```

Rails is going to look in the current folder for a partial file which starts with `_`

Render without quotes

Is still going to use the same partial, but `post` in this case is a variable. I think this is translating to this:

```
<%= render partial: "post", locals: {any_string: your_variable(in this case is post)} %>
```

Again I haven't checked that.

The `_post.html.erb` is the partial, which can look like this:

```
      <b><%=any_string%></b>
```

If `your_variable` which was assigned to `any_string` will contain the string 'My name is'

Your partial will print 'My name is' in bold.

Anyway partial are more complex, and they are used for DRY-ing (Don't repeat yourself) the code.

You can see more examples [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: im sorry, i dint understand much, can you tell me in easy terms

Comment: there is a lot of documentation about partials, the best way for you to learn is by trying it yourself. Anyway which bit you don't understand?